# Cannot add Outgoing COM port for any android device

Tags: bluetooth

My problem is that I need to add outgoing com port to my android device (Nexus 4) Windows 8 x64 connected via Bluetooth.

This is usually done by using Bluetooth settings on the PC and then from "COM ports" tab yo "Add" -> "Outgoing port". However, when I try to add my device it shows me error "The device you have selected does not have a serial port service running". For Incoming port it work fine, but that's not the option I need.

I've also tried to connect Samsung Galaxy S3, Nexus 7 and rooted Nexus 4. Both on Windows 8 x64 and Windows 7 x32. Nothing worked. Then I connected an old phone which uses Symbian 8(?) and it worked fine. Of course the devices are paired before I try do add COM port.

I did good search on Google, but I did not find a way to "turn on serial port service". There's an app (Serial Port API Sample) which supposedly should help with my problem, but it doesn't - I can't get it to work, always showing an error.

I need the outgoing port so I can control my device like a modem by using Matlab.

Comment: What error do you get when you run this app? It seems likely that you would need to root the device to run it. Normal apps shouldn't be able to control the modem directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just based on a bit of research, not my own experience:

Android phones, unlike your Symbian phone which worked, **do not** expose a Hayes-command modem as a built-in externally accessible service. There may well be such an interface *internally* for communicating with the “baseband processor”, but in order to control it from another computer you will have to install an Android app and/or modified OS which forwards the commands it receives from an external source. I don't know whether such an app already exists.

(Further questions on how to get the scheme I described working might be better asked over at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) as they would be essentially about programming Android.)

Comment: Some devices do have serial, cdm, built into adb itself on the device, for example, treating it as a modem device instead of mass storage.

Answer (score 0):

there are some 3rd party app like bluDun and other apps like that are used for as modem service to create a dialup connection

Answer (score -2):

Allow your laptop bluetooth device searchable to others.. then pair from Mobile.. it will help you.. I was facing the same issue but resolved it by doing this trick..

Thanks 
Rajiv K Pundir

Comment: Pairing isn't the problem here, it's specific to creating a serial port service on the phone.